# Does pgfplots support "spatial" plotting?

Tags: pgfplots

As the title states, I like to know if I can plot "spatial" with pgfplots. And I think I have to explain what I mean by that (I couldn't find a good expression in english):

In a pgfplots 3d plot, the axis labels are just rotated in one direction. Example (taken from pgfplots project page at sourceforge.net):

[image]

In contrast, what I would like to see, is this example, done with Origin (taken from the [OriginLab website](http://www.originlab.com/index.aspx?go=Products/Origin/Graphing/3D)):

[image]

So the question is, can I achieve that also with pgfplot?

Comment: Do you want the axis labels to be rendered as if they lay in the x-y-plane? I think this is not a good idea since it decreases the readability …

Comment: Yes, that's what I want. Although it may reduce readability...

Comment: I think one of the things which I really miss from `pgfplots` is that there is no possibility of automated *perspective*, like the second image you posted.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Pgfplots has builtin for rotated axis descriptions using the `sloped` (or `slope like x axis`) keys.

Adding "spatial" labels might be possible with custom transformations. I am thinking of x/y slant transformations which are applied *after* the builtin rotations.

Such a transformation would, of course, depend on the actual view direction (i.e. the choice of `view={<h>}{<v}`).

For the standard view direction, the following could be a starting point which may be useful - or really just a starting point for manual fine tuning.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\tikzset{
    % styles which are used in more than one place below:
    trafo x/.style={
        sloped like x axis,
        xslant=1,
    },
    trafo y/.style={
        sloped like y axis,
        xslant=-1,
        anchor=north,
    },
    trafo z/.style={
        %sloped like z axis,
        yslant=1,
        anchor=east,
    },
}
\pgfplotsset{
    spatial/.style={
        xlabel style={trafo x},
        xticklabel style={trafo x},
        ylabel style={trafo y},
        yticklabel style={trafo y},
            % z was more tricky. This is my current guess:
        every axis z label/.style={%
            at={(ticklabel cs:0.5)},rotate=-90,
            xslant=-1,
            anchor=north,
        },
        zticklabel style={trafo z},
    },
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        min=0,
        max=1,
        xlabel=xlabel,
        ylabel=ylabel,
        zlabel=zlabel,
        spatial,
        ]
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Clearly, the positions of labels might need some correction and the slant values are just guesses.

If you want to elaborate on how this should *really* be done, you can automatically compute a suitable transformation matrix given two axes. For example, the pgfplots macro `pgfplotstransformtoaxisdirection{<axis>}` installs a PGF basic level transformation matrix which implements the `sloped` feature (`<axis>` is one of `x`, `y`, or `z`). I am sure a similar method could be implemented to support spatial plots which look "well enough". If you come up with a general implementation along with tests for many view directions, I can add the result to pgfplots.